# Is there any way to find out how many times a class is used in a page through chrome developer tools?

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, css-selectors

I am trying to debug some code I am using developer tools to debug there are plenty of code in a page so hard get count of each class ,is there  any tool or help that i can find out where  and all the class is used and how many times a class is used. Please help out?[image]

I am trying to find out how many times the class is repeated in whole page, I a 
 hoping there must be a shortcut to find out these things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In chrome developer tools, you can select the "Sources" tab, then in the "Page" tab below, select "(index)" and then just search for your class name by using the ctrl+F shortcut (or command+F on a mac). It will show you the total - like in the screenshot on the bottom left, it shows "1 of 13" for the class-name "row" which is what I was searching for in this example.

[image]

Comment: great finding hope this help others as well

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about how many elements have that class attached to them, you can use javascript to do that.

Open the console tab of the developer tools and run the following query

```
document.querySelectorAll(".<insert-css-class-name>").length
```

If you're not familiar with CSS Selectors check out [this link](https://guide.freecodecamp.org/css/tutorials/css-selectors-cheat-sheet/) for a good starting point.

Comment: I am asking for chrome tools.

Comment: Are you're asking how to get this number from developer tools, without running the script on the developer tools's console tab?

Comment: exactly,You catch it